# SetValuedMap not deserialised correctly by Jackson

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, apache-commons

I am using a `Map<String, SetValuedMap<String, CustomerDomain>>`. I get the correct result while debugging my but following is what is returned by my controller. Seems like Jackson is unable to deserialise the SetValuedMap.

```
{
   "first": {
      empty:false
   },
   "second": {
      empty:false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because data structures like `Map` needs some special logic when de/serialized and any library that converts POJO to JSON has some handling of its own for objects extending `Map` interface.

Also `SetValuedMap` needs this handling since the values are not directly readable from fields or so but with `put(..)` and `get(..)` methods (as it is done in the same way in `Map`).

BUT: `SetValuedMap` does not implement `Map` interface. It has a difference in for example `put()` method return value types and therefore they are "incompatible" in that sense. It is a utility class from Apache commons and not "standard Java".

Therefore Jackson might not have any clue how to deserialize this class. You might need to write custom de/serializer for - for example - `MultiValuedMap`.